# Why can't I get all Instagram posts without using API in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, instagram

Notice as of today March 2020, Instagram has changed considerably, hence, this question is not similar to previous ones.
The issue is that I always get 12 posts instead of all Posts using non Instagram-API ways. I have came across many solutions but all of them only return 12 posts now, even the famous:

**https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1**

This is what I get with **instagram** account that has 6282 posts:

[image]

I have also tried the following trick, but it also returns 12 posts:

```
async function instagramPhotos () {
    // It will contain our photos' links
    const res = []
    
    try {
        const userInfoSource = await Axios.get('https://www.instagram.com/instagram/')

        // userInfoSource.data contains the HTML from Axios
        const jsonObject = userInfoSource.data.match(/<script type="text\/javascript">window\._sharedData = (.*)<\/script>/)[1].slice(0, -1)

        const userInfo = JSON.parse(jsonObject)
        // Retrieve only the first 10 results
        const mediaArray = userInfo.entry_data.ProfilePage[0].graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges
        for (let media of mediaArray) {
            const node = media.node
            
            // Process only if is an image
            if ((node.__typename && node.__typename !== 'GraphImage')) {
                continue
            }

            // Push the thumbnail src in the array
            res.push(node.thumbnail_src)
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Unable to retrieve photos. Reason: ' + e.toString())
    }
    
    return res
}
```

There are many npm modules that claim they can get feed without using Instagram API but at the end they only return 12 posts, for example: (**[instagram-nodejs-without-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-nodejs-without-api)**)

I run the following code, and I also get only **12 posts**:

```
let Instagram = require('instagram-nodejs-without-api');
Instagram = new Instagram()

const username="instagram"
const password="123hola" 

Instagram.getCsrfToken().then((csrf) =>
{
  Instagram.csrfToken = csrf;
}).then(() =>
{
  return Instagram.auth(username, password).then(sessionId =>
  {
    Instagram.sessionId = sessionId

    return Instagram.getUserDataByUsername(username).then((t) =>
    {
        console.log(t)
    })

  })
}).catch(console.error);
```

My next step is to perform web scraping over Instagram profile but it is very slow specially when images are around 6000, Is there any elegant approach to get these posts? I only want to get my posts so I don't mind to be logged In.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I needed to get posts from a concrete profile, I opened the profile in chrome browser, opened the console and runned the following code to get all posts:

```
//LOOPING ALL (credit www.hamzadiaz.com)
let posts = []
setInterval(()=>{
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('v1Nh3 kIKUG  _bz0w'); 
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) {
 if(!posts.includes(inputs[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href)){
    posts.push(inputs[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href)
  }
}
},500);
```

Comment: Is there a solution as such for server side?

Comment: yes, using selenium scrapper in python or puppeteer in Nodejs and scrape all posts using similar approach